# How to install vim plugin(EasyMotion) in Linux?

Tags: linux, vim, vi

How to install vim plugin(EasyMotion) in Linux? And the plugin is here:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526

Answer (score 8):

Give [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) a shot. It's simpler than Pathogen in my experience and certainly simpler than installing the plugin manually.

Installing a plugin with Vundle is as simple as adding the plugin name to your .vimrc:

```
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
```

Then you would run `:BundleInstall` and you're done!

Take a look at the [Vundle Github](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) page to see how to set it up. It only takes a minute, and it will save you plenty of headache down the road when you inevitably need to remove or update plugins.

Comment: Looks nice, will have to try it!

Answer (score 5):

You should merge the `autoload`, `plugin`, and `doc` with a directory of your runtime (inside vim type `:echo &runtimepath` to know what locations are suitable). Typically put them in `~/.vim/`.

After that you can run `:helptags ~/.vim/` to refresh the help index.

**Edit**: You seem new to Linux.

In a command-line window:

```
cd                           # will go to your home path, equivalent to « cd ~ » or « cd $HOME »
mkdir .vim                   # will create a directory named « .vim »
cd .vim
mkdir plugin
cd plugin
wget 'https://raw.github.com/vim-scripts/pathogen.vim/2e20ff61bcc440c8dbceb8036b8b127cd4d555dc/plugin/pathogen.vim'
echo 'call pathogen#infect()' >> ~/.vimrc
cd ..
mkdir bundle                 # will create a « bundle » directory
cd bundle
wget 'http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=16838'
unzip Lokaltog-vim-easymotion-1.3-0-g667a668.zip
rm Lokaltog-vim-easymotion-1.3-0-g667a668.zip
```

Note that in Nautilus (default file browser if you are using the Gnome Desktop Environment), CTRL-H shows hidden files (those that begin with a dot).

Comment: I would recommend that @user1063434 install and use pathogen https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen since it makes it a lot easier to organize and maintain his vim plugins.

Comment: I still don't understand , I 'm a dummy, please simple tell me how to merge the three directory and where can I find .vim